# Ionic Framwork: GridLayout with multiple rows and column of image placed from an arrayItem using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i need to implement grid layout of images with multiple rows and columns in ionic framework. can anybody help me

```
 <ion-content ng-controller="MenuCtrl as menuCtrl" >
     <div class="row responsive-md">
      <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="image in images">
         <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" />
     </div>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: have u used any plugin to get the images from the file?

Comment: no i don't used any pulgin for images.,

Comment: i am getting images displayed as list  but i want to displayed as like(matrix )grid.

Comment: i have added a answer with my structure, it might helpfull for you. it will give me the images in matrix grid

Answer (score 0):

I have used to display my images in rows and columns by the following format. This will be help you. To work on css, you can use the browser style with responsive and apply the css to your ionic.

```
<div class="resize">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="images-align">
        <figure ng-repeat="(imageKey, imageUrl) in images" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >
            <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
        </figure>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```